# Calculating $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{4}{4}+\frac{9}{8}+\frac{16}{16}+\frac{25}{32}+\cdots+\frac{k^2}{2^k}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I want to know the value of $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{4}{4}+\frac{9}{8}+\frac{16}{16}+\frac{25}{32}+\cdots+\frac{k^2}{2^k}+\cdots$$
I added up to $k=50$ and got the value $5.999999999997597$, so it seems that it converges to $6.$ But, I don't know how to get the exact value. Is there any other simple method to calculate it?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643206/trouble-calculating-sum-of-the-series-sum-left-fracn22n-right – both found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7Bk%5E2%7D%7B2%5Ek%7D%24)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we start with the power series
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x} $$
(valid for $|x|<1$) and differentiate then multiply by $x$, we get
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
If we once again differentiate then multiply by $x$, the result is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2x^k=\frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}$$
and setting $x=\frac{1}{2}$ shows that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^22^{-k}=\frac{\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{1}{8}}=6 $$
as you guessed.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_i x^i$. Differentiate it once to get $\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{1}{1-x} \right] = \frac{d}{dx} \sum_i x^i = \sum_i i x^{i-1}$. Differentiate again to get $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \left[ \frac{1}{1-x} \right] = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \sum_i x^i = \sum_i i (i-1)  x^{i-2}$.

Now, plug in $x= \frac{1}{2}$ and adjust indices in teh summations.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, note that if $T = \sum_{k \geq 0}k^2 2^{-k}$ then $$T = 2T-T = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{2k+1}{2^k} = 2\sum_{k \geq 0}\frac{k}{2^k} + \sum_{k \geq 0}2^{-k} $$

But we can let $S= \sum_{k \geq 0}k2^{-k}$ and note that $$S = 2S-S = \sum_{k\geq 0}2^{-k} = 2.$$

Hence $T = 2\cdot 2 + 2 = 6.$